# Multiplying two ordinals where one has been raised to power of $\omega$. Term order matters?

Tags: set-theory, ordinals

When multiplying two ordinals that are both raised to some power, my book says that one adds the exponents. But what happens if one of the exponents is $\omega$ ?  Does the order of the terms matter ?

here is an example from my book:

$\omega * \omega^n =   \omega^{1+n}$

Now, what if 'n' = $\omega$ ?

I am guessing that 
  $\omega^\omega *\omega  =   \omega^{\omega+1}$

But is this true:  $\omega^\omega *\omega =   \omega  * \omega^\omega$
?

I am asking because my understanding is that adding the exponents " $\omega + 1$ " would be different from adding the exponents " $1 + \omega$ "  if the rules of ordinal addition were being followed.  (Since under ordinal addition rules $1 + \omega = \omega$, while
$ \omega + 1  \neq \omega$

Thanks in advance for any guidance you can provide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you mention, addition of ordinals is not commutative. And you gave the example $$\omega=1+\omega \neq \omega +1$$

Based on that you get $\omega^\omega \cdot \omega  =   \omega^{\omega+1}$ while $\omega \cdot \omega^\omega  =   \omega^{1+\omega}=\omega^\omega$. And those last two ordinals are different. More precisely $$\omega^\omega < \omega^{\omega+1}$$

Answer (score 0):

No, we have $\omega \times \omega^\omega=\omega^\omega$.

Note that we have $\omega \times \delta < \omega^\omega$ for all $\delta <\omega^\omega$, so the limit is $\omega^\omega$ and thus gives $\omega \times \omega^\omega=\omega^\omega$.

Another way to look at it: $\omega \times \omega^\omega = \omega^{1+\omega} = \omega^\omega$ by the rule in your book.

Comment: This is an awkward argument - it's also the case that $\delta\times\omega\lt\omega^\omega$ for all $\delta\lt\omega^\omega$, so you can't really talk about limits in the way you're trying to.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki But that is not how ordinal multiplication works. You have to take the 'limit' on the rightmost ordinal. If that one is a limit ordinal.